# Safari bookmarks to CSV or excel

Tags: safari, bookmarks

is there a way to import or convert the bookmarks.html generated by safari bookmark export menu into a CSV that can be imported to excel with 2 columns, URL and Description?
The way it works actually is that the HTML file contains only descriptions with a clickable link and whether you import it to excel, you get only one column with the same theme: clickable links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Export bookmarks from Safari into `bookmarks.html`
- Open Terminal and run

  ```
  sed -n '/<DT><A HREF/s/^.*<DT><A HREF="\(.*\)">\(.*\)<\/A>/\1;"\2"/p' bookmarks.html > bookmarks.csv
  ```

This will create a `;` separated list containing the URL and the name (in "").

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was looking for! Thank you!